# ASP.NET, MVC 5, PostalCode Validation, Numberpicker

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I don't want the PostalCode field to be required, but I do want to use the   `[DataType(DataType.PostalCode)]` Annotation to validate entries when made.

I'd also like to know how to eliminate the numberpicker property in this field when it displays on the `Create.cshtml` page.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Testimonial.Models
{
    // Collection of User Input fields
    public class Client
    {
        public virtual int ClientId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(160)]
        [Display(Name="Business Name")]
        public virtual string BizName { get; set; }
        [StringLength(160)]
        [Display(Name="First Name")]
        public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
        [StringLength(160)]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
        [StringLength(160)]
        public virtual string WebSite { get; set; }
        [StringLength(160)]
        public virtual string Address { get; set; }
        [StringLength(160)]
        public virtual string City { get; set; }
        public virtual Enum.State State { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.PostalCode)]
        public virtual int Postalcode { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        public virtual string Phone { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public virtual string Email { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Service Type")]
        public virtual int ServiceTypeId { get; set; }
        public virtual ServiceType ServiceType { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Testimonial")]
        public virtual int ReviewId { get; set; }
        //[Required(ErrorMessage="You must enter a testimonial.")]
        public virtual Review Review { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Postal code should be a string - otherwise a zip with a leading zero i.e.  02188  would be saved as 2188.

```
[DataType(DataType.PostalCode)]
public virtual string Postalcode { get; set; }
```

Comment: Why `string?` Strings are nullable already. Also as another point, Canada and many other countries use letters in their postal codes. Even if you are building a US app, it doesn't mean someone doesn't have a summer home in Canada or Australia or anywhere else that uses letters as their address.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it.  I'm just learning, but I did run across this same display error on a published site.

Comment: You're quite welcome Linda. We're all learning - if we're lucky